# proxy setting in ubuntu

Tags: apt, virtualbox, proxy

I use a business network , and I tried to configure proxy settings in ubuntu. After this I obtain this error:

```
sudo apt-get update
Scaricamento di:1 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de wily InRelease [34,6 kB]
100% [1 InRelease gpgv 34,6 kB] [Connessione a 137.183.234.7 (137.183.234.7)]Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ubuntu.unitedcolo.de_ubuntu_dists_wily_InReIgn http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de wily InRelease                               
E: Errore GPG: http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de wily InRelease: Il file con la firma in chiaro non è valido, ottenuto "NODATA" (la rete richiede autenticazione?)
```

Here my configuration of the file apt.conf :

```
linuda@linuda-VirtualBox:~$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://p****:Co****@137.***.***.***:8080";
Acquire::http::proxy "http://p****:Co****@137.***.***.***:8080";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://p****:Co****@137.***.***.***:8080";
Acquire::socks::proxy "https://p****:Co****@137.***.***.***:8080";
linuda@linuda-VirtualBox:~$
```

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: This is a very common question. I am not sure why apt will not use the system proxy =(